# How to get bundle id in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, bundle-identifier, package-name

I used the below method to get the app name and packageName but I need Bundle id for iPhone users.
I want to share an app link.
I did it in android but on iPhone, I need bundle id.

```
 Future<Null> _initPackageInfo() async {
        final PackageInfo info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
        setState(() {
          _packageInfo = info;
          packageName = info.packageName;
          appName = info.appName;
          buildNumber = info.buildNumber;
        });
      }
```

Comment: `info.packageName` should work on iOS. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Bostrot - No - it doesn't return the numeric ID it returns the same string as the Android package name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**get_version**](https://pub.dev/packages/get_version) package . It's the easiest way

**Installing :**

```
 dependencies:
   get_version: any
```

**Usage:**

```
String projectAppID;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  projectAppID = await GetVersion.appID;
} on PlatformException {
  projectAppID = 'Failed to get app ID.';
}
```

> You can use it as String inside anything you want like Text widget etc ...

---

**Another extract of get_version in a small application :**

```
import 'package:get_version/get_version.dart';    
  class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _projectAppID = '';
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }    
  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  initPlatformState() async {
    String projectAppID;
    try {
      projectAppID = await GetVersion.appID;
    } catch (e) {
      projectAppID = 'Failed to get app ID.';
    }
    setState(() {
      _projectAppID = projectAppID;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListTile(
          leading: new Icon(Icons.info),
          title: const Text('App ID'),
          subtitle: new Text(_projectAppID),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 134):

To find the project name manually, you can look in AndroidManifest.xml or in Info.plist.

### Android

In Android the package name is in the AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    package="com.example.appname">
```

### iOS

In iOS the package name is the bundle identifier in Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

which is found in *Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj*:

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.example.appname;
```

### See also

- [How to change package name in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter)

Comment: please more be clear `https://apps.apple.com/app/id$appId` i still only get package name , not the id12312312312 the bundle id

Comment: the question looking for bundleID not package name, but i have solved by lookup or get from `iTunes` API.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo, I wasn't aware of a separate bundle id besides `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` before. That's good that you added a new answer for other people who come here.

Answer (score 15):

In iOS portion of a Flutter project **Product Bundle Identifier** is in `project.pbxproj` file in path:

`[your-flutter-project-dir]\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj`

and that is specified as following:

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.app.flutter.example;
```

Note in that this value is same as `Android Package Name` in Flutter projects.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to get the IOS bundle ID manually, here is how

1. In Android Studio select the root folder (ex. `flutte_name`)
2. In the taskbar go to `Tools>>Flutter>>Open IOS Modules in Xcode`
3. In Xcode open Runner and under `Identity/Bundle Identifier` there is your ID

[image]

Comment: How can I get IOS bundle ID if I am using android studio on windows 11?

Comment: @pawan As far as I am concerned Xcode requires a Mac/macOS. If you have windows I would probably go for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128145/11003497) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to update it to a custom name rather than com.example.appName anyways so you can check out this package called change_app_name on pub.dev here https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name

Super simple I just did it myself. Add the package to your pubspec file and than in a terminal in the root folder type in "flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.company.app" change the last part to whatever you want and it will update your whole project with the new name you chose

Comment: I think this answer belongs over here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter instead.

Answer (score 1):

what i see you have already get the package name by `info.packageName;` and appName `info.appName;`

1. try request to `http://itunes.apple.com/search?media=software&country={countryID}&term={appName}`
2. you can test by **curl** instead of **browser** ( this will return file.txt )

```
curl --location -g --request GET 'http://itunes.apple.com/search?media=software&country=id&term=appName' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' | jq
```

in other solution some people can get it from

```
// if doesnt work try with these lookup
itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.apple.Pages
```

```
 | jq // these for make response beutifull
```

response json

```
....
....
bundleId: '212312xxxxxx'
trackViewUrl: 'https://apps.apple.com/id/app/appName/id212312xxxxxx'
....
....
```

i use these concept to **self update** from **backend** ( SplashScreen / check app version ) will popUP alert forced user to go to the market place.