# How to change package name in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

Is there any way to change Package Name of Flutter project?

I want to change package name and application name in flutter project.

Comment: Just search and replace all occurrences of the old package name in all files. There is no command or similar to update the name yet.

Comment: When you create a new project you can specify the package name with `flutter create --org com.domain app_name`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change app package name in Flutter without using Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400655/how-to-change-app-package-name-in-flutter-without-using-android-studio)

Comment: @JannieTheunissen That question seems to be more specific than this one. If anything, that one should be closed as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @Victor The `app_name` will be appended as a package so in the end you will have something like `com.domain.app_name`. So if you have a domain subdomain like `app.foo.com` and you want to create the app with name `app` you will end-up with `com.foo.app.app` which is ugly

Comment: Surely there's a plugin to manage this by now?

Answer (score 716, accepted):

**For Android App Name**

Change the label name in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
<application
  android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
  android:label="TheNameOfYourApp"
```

**For Package Name**

Change the package name in your `AndroidManifest.xml` (in 3 of them, folders: main, debug and profile, according what environment you want to deploy) file:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.package.name">
```

Also in your `build.gradle` file inside app folder

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Finally, change the package in your `MainActivity.java` class (if the MainActivity.java is not available, check the MainActivity.kt)

```java
package your.package.name;

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
```

Change the directory name:

From:

```
  android\app\src\main\java\com\example\name
```

To:

```
  android\app\src\main\java\your\package\name
```

---

**EDITED : 27-Dec-18**

for **package name** just change in build `build.gradle` only

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

**For iOS**

Change the bundle identifier from your `Info.plist` file inside your `ios/Runner` directory.

```xml
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.your.packagename</string>
```

**UPDATE**

To avoid renaming the package and bundle identifier, you can start your project using this command in your terminal:

```
flutter create --org com.yourdomain appname
```

Comment: I had to update the directory name below too (changing 'example' to 'woods') C:\Users\andytwoods\IdeaProjects\gear_log\android\app\src\main\java\com\woods\gearlog

Comment: How about for iOS?

Comment: @Suragch change the bundle identifier from your Info.plist file

Comment: My bundle identifier is `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`. Where is that variable hiding?

Comment: search the variable : PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER

Comment: PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER is stored  in multiple places  in project.pbxproj file the ios/Runner.xcodeproj directory.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the appID must be in the format of 3 words separated by dots.

Comment: So I only have to change the package name  in  build.gradle file ? how does the manifest and directory structure get updated?

Comment: The MainActivity.kt for the new flutter auto generated app

Comment: @diegoveloper Do I have to search and replace all PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER values inside project.pbxproj OR I can simply update Info.plist once?

Comment: You can open xcworkspace file and change bundle identifier there for the target. Info.plist will pick that variable.

Comment: if you get "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'." - There is also a debug manifest at android > app > src > debug > AndroidManifest.xml You might also want to change the package name there as well

Comment: I don't have this android\app\src\main\java\com\example\name directory in my project should I create it?

Comment: @diegoveloper may be you can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186598/flutter-notificationlistener-in-tabcontroller-for-infinite-scroll

Comment: Getting this error for Android `Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at has a different declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Note that most new Flutter apps come with MainActivity.kt instead of MainActivity.java. Remember to rename the package declaration at the top of this one and move it to a subfolder that reflects the new package name.

Comment: Additionally i have updated. `<activity android:name='your.package.name.MainActivity'` .. in AndroidManifest.xml  .  @ShajeelAfzal : this could be the reason for your error.

Comment: easy way to update package name is https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name

Comment: namespace also needs to be updated in build.gradle
android {
    namespace "com.newpackage.name"
}

Comment: Also worth mentioning to update the Bundle ID in Xcode unter Targets > General > Indentity > Bundle Identifier

Answer (score 153):

Changing name manually doesn't seem to work, throws gradle errors, well in my case it does throw error.

So I usually create a new flutter project.

I use below mentioned command to create a new flutter app

```
flutter create --org com.yourdomain appname
```

your project will have the package name as ->  `com.yourdomain.appname`

---

if you just want to keep your package name as `com.appname` then make some changes as below

```
flutter create --org com appname
```

to add java instead of `kotlin` for `android` add `-a java`

```
flutter create -a java --org com.yourdomain appname
```

---

**EDIT**

---

If you have already created a project you can use [change_app_package_name](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name) package to change the package name.

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.package.appname
```

Comment: 'flutter create --org com.yourcompany --project-name new_app_name .' (add the period if you are inside the existing project -- you should trash the android and ios folders first to have them regenerated). MAKE A BACKUP should be an important prerequisite for the answer.

Comment: you can create a new project and then just copy over the pubspec.yaml dependencies, run pub get, and then copy your dart files from the lib folder

Answer (score 96):

For those like me that doesn't like to change specific files, I've used https://pub.dev/packages/rename.

Using this, you simply run these commands in your terminal and your app name and identifiers will be changed.pub global run

Installing: `pub global activate rename`

And then, Run this command inside your flutter project root.

`pub global run rename --bundleId com.example.android.app --target android`

Comment: This package worked great right out the box. Thanks!

Comment: Is this command just to change the package name for android apps or does it work for any platform?

Comment: @Ndrslmpk I believe any platform. At least that's what the docs are saying

Comment: Who can say that for sure?

Comment: @Ndrslmpk in the docs they mention that they are supporting a bunch of platforms: https://pub.dev/packages/rename

Comment: Tested for android and ios platforms, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 53):

### Android

In Android the package name is in the AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    package="com.example.appname">
```

### iOS

In iOS the package name is the bundle identifier in Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

which is found in *Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj*:

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.example.appname;
```

### Changing the name

The package name is found in more than one location, so to change the name you should search the whole project for occurrences of your old project name and change them all.

Android Studio and VS Code:

- Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Linux/Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

---

*Thanks to [diegoveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter/51550358#comment96996272_51550358) for help with iOS.*

## Update:

After coming back to this page a few different times, I'm thinking it's just easier and cleaner to start a new project with the right name and then copy the old files over.

Comment: Hi I have a question. It might not related to Flutter topic but how can I push the renamed project to a current project on github if I create a new project?

Comment: @Ooto, You can delete the old project (except for the `.git` directory at the root) and then put the new project in the same directory as the old one. Then commit and push the changes.

Answer (score 35):

As easy as possible use this [change_app_package_name](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name) package first add dependencie

```
 dev_dependencies: 
  change_app_package_name: lates version
```

and then run this command

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name
```

Comment: but didnt change all package name in lib/ folder / file.dart , we must search all old_name and replace all. any have same issue ?

Answer (score 33):

**This is how i renamed package for both ios and android**

1. Go to build.gradle in app module and rename `applicationId "com.company.name"`
2. Go to Manifest.xml in `app/src/main` and rename `package="com.company.name"` and `android:label="App Name"`
3. Go to Manifest.xml in `app/src/debug` and rename `package="com.company.name"`
4. Go to Manifest.xml in `app/src/profile` and rename `package="com.company.name"`
5. Go to `app/src/main/kotlin/com/something/something/MainActivity.kt` and rename `package="com.company.name"`
6. Go to `app/src/main/kotlin/` and rename each directory so that the structure looks like `app/src/main/kotlin/com/company/name/`
7. Go to `pubspec.yaml` in your project and change `name: something` to `name: name`, example :- if package name is `com.abc.xyz` the `name: xyz`
8. Go to each dart file in lib folder and rename the imports to the modified name.
9. Open XCode and open the runner file and click on Runner in project explorer.
10. Go to General -> double click on Bundle Identifier -> rename it to `com.company.name`
11. Go to Info.plist click on Bundle name -> rename it to your App Name.
12. close everything -> go to your flutter project and run this command in terminal `flutter clean`

Comment: I don't have a kotlin folder and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 30):

Change `name` attribute in `pubspec.yaml`  (line 1)

For the name of apk, change `android:label`  in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: MainActivity.java or mainActivity.kt change is required

Comment: After do what you said appears thousands of problem.
Flutter 3.13.6 
2023

Answer (score 23):

**Quickest and cleanest way to change your package name!**

### Warning:

> If you have edited the contents of the folders **android/**, **ios/** and **windows/**, you need to make sure you have those changes backed up somewhere before proceeding.

**1. Delete your folders at the root of your flutter project:**

- `android/`
- `ios/`
- `windows/`
- `build/`

Let's say you want to rename from ***`com.oldcompany.oldproject`*** to ***`com.newcompany.newproject`***.

**2. Launch the following command from the root of your project:**

```
flutter create --org com.newcompany --project-name newproject .
```

If you want to limit your projects to specific platforms (for example android and iOS) run :

```
flutter create --platforms=android,ios --org com.newcompany --project-name newproject .
```

**PS:** 
To make sure everything is set up correctly, you can search for your package names in your files, by running the following commands

```
grep --color -r com.oldcompany.oldproject *
```

```
grep --color -r com.newcompany.newproject *
```

Comment: This is the best answer, definitely the cleanest and quick solution! In case you've modified platform specific files, be sure to backup them and put the changes back. The easiest way is to use GIT repo and go through changes this process did.

Comment: This is the quickest and most straightforward solution by far. Please remember to back up any files in **android/** and **ios/** before deleting them!

Comment: I also deleted macos/ and web/ folders; However I didn't deleted the build/ folder (I didn't have it). Then the flutter create command re-generated all those folders in a clean way. Great.

Answer (score 21):

1. First, run this in your terminal

   `dart pub global activate rename`
2. Run this in your Flutter Project Root Directory

   `dart pub global run rename --bundleId com.company.appname --target android`

This will update the gradle build file with right id in `defaultConfig`

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.appname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
 }
```

And that's everything, now you changed your package name :)

[image]

Comment: In my case this wasn't enough...Many errors were happening because a lot of auto-generated folders and imports inside the code had the old package name. I had to change the MainActivity.kt import manually among many other folder and code changes. And even worse...I forgot about my local git and my remote git...It'd be a good idea to create a new branch to attempt this...just in case...

Comment: currently in 2024 this is the syntax - ```dart pub global run rename setBundleId -v com.ipurim```

Answer (score 17):

If you not started the project, this is the best possible way.

```
flutter create --org com.yourdomain appname
```

If you already created the project, install this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name) in your dev_dependencies and run this command.

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name
```

This will change all the complex stuffs of changing package name in android. And right click on the iOS folder of flutter and open with Xcode.

In **Xcode** > select **Runner** > In **general** tab you can change the **bundle Identifier.**

This is the easiest possible way if you already created a project and don't know the complexity of change the package name.

Answer (score 11):

**Updated** You have to change the package name to your desired package name in these
five locations.

```
1.) src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml
2.) src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
3.) src/main/AdroidManifest.xml
4.) app/build.gradle
     build.gradle .
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId
       }
5.) MainActivity.java or MainActivity.kt on "package"
```

the last step is to run `flutter clean`

Comment: when changing package name , in the module-android , need to change folders name. ( example : com.google.app ) has 3 folder named com & google & app .

Answer (score 11):

**On Visual Studio code**

Edit > Replace in Files

[image: vs code replace in files]

***On Android studio***

**1. Right click on your project > Replace in path**

[image: replace in path]

**2. Write your old package and new package > Replace all**

[image: replace all screenshot]

Answer (score 10):

According to the official flutter documentation you just need to change the `ApplicationId` in `app/build.gradle` directory. Then you have to just build your apk and the package name of the manifest file will be changed according to the `ApplicationId` you changed in `build.gradle`. Because of flutter while building an apk and google play both consider `ApplicationId` from build.gradle. This solution worked for me.

source: [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html)

Answer (score 9):

change in all **AndroidManifest.xml** files of your Flutter Project, --> **package="your.name.app**"
(app/src/debug/**AndroidManifest.xml**) and
(app/src/main/**AndroidManifest.xml**) and (app/src/profile/**AndroidManifest.xml**)

good look !!

Answer (score 7):

### Change App Package Name easily using `change_app_package_name` package

just add the above package in dev dependencies

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  change_app_package_name: ^0.1.2
```

and run the following command, replace "com.new.package.name" with your new package name

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name
```

#### [Package Link on Pub Dev](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name)

[image: screenshot of Package]

Answer (score 7):

To change  **package name** in flutter , you have to do it for **all platforms**.

**To make it easier**, I suggest you to use [**rename**](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) package .

Just run this command inside your flutter project root.

```
pub global run rename --bundleId com.onat.networkApp
```

> Here, com.onat.networkApp is your package name

To target a specific platform use the "-t" option.
e.g:

```
pub global run rename --bundleId com.example.android.app -t android
```

You can learn more about **rename** package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/rename)

Answer (score 6):

the right to change path for default way for both Android and Ios.

**for Android**

open AndroidManifest.xml,

- go to this path.

app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

- select on package name, and right click,

[image]

- after click on rename, rename popup(dialog) show.

[image]

- enter the new package name here,

[image]

- after changes name text, click on refactor button.

**__________________________________________________________________________**

for **Ios**

- select ios folder from drawer, and right click on these,

[image]

- select,and  double click on Runner in drawer,and then select General

[image]

- and then, change your Bundle Identifier(Package Name).
- after changes Bundle Identifier(Package Name), Your Package Name is
  changed for Ios.

Answer (score 5):

Change App Package Name with `single command` by using following package. It makes the process very easy and fast.

> flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name

https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name

Answer (score 3):

Even if my answer wont be accepted as the correct answer, I just feel all these answers above caused me to have more problems here is how I fixed it

1. Get Sublime Text (crazy, right? No, just follow my steps)
2. Click on file and select open folder, then choose the folder of the project you are working on
3. Now click on Find from the Tabs, and select find in files or just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  (for Windows users, for mac users you already know the drill)
4. Now copy and paste exactly the name of the package you want to change in the Find section and paste in the replace section what you would like to replace the package name with.
5. Click on FIND (do not click on REPLACE just yet).
6. Now clicking on Find lists all available package name in your project which matches your search criteria, if you are satisfied with this then repeat from no. 3 but this time click on REPLACE.
7. Rebuild your project and have fun

Conclusion: a simple find and replace program is all you need to sort this problem out, and I strongly recommend Sublime Text 3 for that.

Comment: It is required to also update the file path as @diegoveloper suggested in his answer. By searching, we cannot search the path.

Answer (score 3):

After trying all of the above. Simple work for me to rename package flutter with
**Android Studio**:

Step 1:

Mac: `Command + Shift + R`

Linux/Windows: `Ctrl + Shift + R`

After change to new package and press `Replace All` and wait **Android Studio** run finish.

[image: flutter rename package in Android Studio]

Step 2:

Next, go to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your.package.name">
```

and copy `package name` and do the same Step 1 to rename `package` in `AndroidManifest` and `build.gradle`.

Finally, change the package in your MainActivity.java class (if the MainActivity.java is not available, check the MainActivity.kt)

```
package your.package.name;

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
```

Change the directory name.
For details see the following link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/9405238):

From:

`android\app\src\main\java\com\example\name`

To:

`android\app\src\main\java\your\new_package\name`

Answer (score 3):

Add Change App Package Name to your pubspec.yaml in dev_dependencies: section.

dev_dependencies:

change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0

Update dependencies
flutter pub get

Run this command to change the package name.

flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name

Where com.new.package.name is the new package name that you want for your app. replace it with any name you want.

Answer (score 2):

I had two manifest.xml file in my app section,so I needed to change package name in both[image: Here you can see]

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t like changing files in such a way then alternative way would be to use this package.

https://pub.dev/packages/rename

```
rename --bundleId com.newpackage.appname
pub global run rename --appname "Your New App Name"
```

Using this, you simply run these 2 commands in your terminal and your app name and identifiers will be changed.pub global run

Comment: This seems to have only changed the applicationId in one place (build.gradle). It did not update AndroidManifest. Did you get a different result?

Answer (score 2):

EASY way, in editor search E.g.VS CODE `your.package.name` E.g `com.example.application` through all files.,

- 3 AndroidManifest files(profile, debug, main)
- 1 build.gradle
- 1 java
  or kt file

these will popup

Replace all these and voila. If you have already build your project, numerous files will popup in the `build` directory, you can ignore that files, no need to change those

Answer (score 2):

As of Android Studio 4.1.3, changing package name couldn't be more easy.

If you don't use Firebase or any other external service, just change the package name in these files:

1. In the build.gradle (app) file
2. In the Manifest file (main, debug and profile)
3. Package import in code files (Android Studio. will handle the changes)

**NOTE**: Also change the directory name (under Kotlin or Java).

If you use Firebase or any other external Service, you need to change the package name there too.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using VS Code, you could replace all your com.example to your package name

To do so, `CTRL+SHIFT+H`
set the word to replace `com.example`
set the word replace with `[your package]`
then `REPLACE ALL`

Answer (score 1):

In Android, change application id in

**> build.gradle**

file and iOS change

**>  bundle name from project settings.**

Answer (score 1):

I have done global search for existing package name, and changed all fields with new package name. Then changed

> app->src->main->yourOldFolderName

folder name as per new package name. After that, changed all imported package name to new package name. It was a lot of manual work but was worth it, without any issues.

Note: Watch for the blank space before package name it may give built errors

Short-cuts:

> global search- ctrl+shift+f

To change package

> file search- ctrl+f

To change import package name

Answer (score 1):

**Use this plugin (2022)**

`https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name`

**Usage**

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name

Old Package Name: com.example.oldname
Updating build.gradle File
Updating Main Manifest file
Updating Debug Manifest file
Updating Profile Manifest file
Project is using kotlin
Updating MainActivity.kt
Creating New Directory Structure
Deleting old directories
```

Comment: no iOS support with this package

Comment: use this package it supports iOS, display name, etc. https://pub.dev/packages/rename

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this official documentation by Google: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html

Application ID should be changed in Build.gradle, while package name can be changed in AndroidManifest.xml.

However one should be careful changing package name.

Also while re uploading the app, one should be careful since it matches the application ID of previously uploaded app with new upload.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the proper solution for the problem. But you can just create a new project with the package name you want and then copy all the source files to the new project from your existing projects.

**NOTE: You'll have to copy all the contents of pubspec too. In the case of firebase and other APIs, that solution may be a bit lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

In Vs Code, What I did was search and replace it all and it worked! like a charm.

com.example.appName

restart your vs code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step by step

1. Open the project folder in your preferred IDE.
2. Locate the `pubspec.yaml` file in the root of the project.
3. Add the following line to the `pubspec.yaml` file:

`name: <your_new_package_name>`

4. In the same directory, open `android folder.
5. Open `app` folder and locate the `build.gradle` file.
6. Replace the current package name with your new package name.
7. Open `ios` folder.
8. Locate `Runner.xcodeproj` file in the `ios` folder.
9. Open the `info.plist` file.
10. Replace the current package name with your new package name.
11. Save all changes and close the files.
12. Run the command `flutter clean`.
13. Finally, run the command `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
for F in $(grep -F "com.old.old" . -Rl); do sed -i 's|com\.new\.new|com\.new\.new|g' ${F}; done
```

Answer (score 0):

The very easy solution is to go to AndroidManifest.xml.

Copy the package name from the second line in the AndroidManifest file, which is "com.example.anwout"

Then, use global replacement to change the package name throughout the whole project.

For global replacement of package name:

```
          In Android Studio, press Ctrl + Shift + R.
          In VS Code, press Ctrl + Shift + H."
```

[image]

And press 'Replace All' button

Package name will be replaced in this simple way in whole project.