# Running flutter app on physical android error

Tags: android, flutter

I try to run the app onto my physical android phone, and i get this error

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
adb: failed to install /Users/User/AndroidStudioProjects/appname/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_PACKAGE_NAME: Invalid manifest package: must have at least one '.' separator]
Error launching application on Pixel XL.
```

I had just updated my flutter from v.0.3.1 to v.0.7.3 and also prepped it for deployment and now im getting this error

i have no idea how to go about fixing this, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: and what is your package name?

Comment: im not exactly sure what specifically that is, but im pretty sure its io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication

Comment: oh i found it, yeah its not separated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This error is because you have capital letters in your package name like this.

```
Com.example.anubhav;
```

You need to change it to small letters:

```
com.example.anubhav;
```

You can refer to this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter) which tells you how to change package name in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

It's a error to install your app at your mobile emulator, you have to clean it:

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Wipe Data (delete datas from emulator)
3. Open emulator
4. Try to run app

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's give you alert in your physical device for installation of App.
please allow to install option.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with your answer?