# How to register Apple App Id Bundle for Flutter app?

Tags: ios, flutter

I finished a Flutter app and I was preparing the iOS version for release. The Flutter [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios) says to add an App ID, but I can't remember what I called it in Flutter. In pubspec.yaml it just has a `name` setting, but that isn't the bundle name. Also do I use a wildcard name for my app in the iOS settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the package name by looking for the bundle identifier in Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

which is found in *Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj*:

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.example.appname;
```

The Flutter [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#register-a-bundle-id) specify that you should select the Explicit App ID. Thus, you should use

```
com.example.appname
```

and not

```
com.example.*
```

#### Alternative solution

You can also open the ios/Runner folder in Xcode as described in the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#review-xcode-project-settings).

#### See also

- [Preparing an iOS App for Release](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios) Flutter docs
- [Registering an App ID in the Apple Developers site](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle)
- [How to change package name in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

**Register a Bundle ID**

Every iOS application is associated with a Bundle ID, a unique identifier registered with Apple. To register a Bundle ID for your app, follow these steps:

Open the [App IDs](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle) page of your developer account.
Click **+** to create a new Bundle ID.
Enter an app name, select **Explicit App ID**, and enter an ID.
Select the services your app uses, then click **Continue**.
On the next page, confirm the details and click **Register** to register your Bundle ID.