# Set package in VS Code when creating a project

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

Is there a way to set default package in VS Code? (com.example.myproject) I can only do this in Android studio. So I used it to create a project and then I open it in VS Code.

I mean when creating via: (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ➡ New flutter project)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To change the default organization from `com.example` to your own, perform the following steps:

1. Open **Settings** in VS Code
2. Type "flutter" in the search bar
3. Select **Dart & Flutter** under Extensions
4. Scroll down to **Dart: Flutter Create Organization**
5. Click **Edit in settings.json**
6. Add the following line to the JSON list:

   ```
   "dart.flutterCreateOrganization": "com.mydomain",
   ```
7. Save the file and create a new project

Your package name should be correct now and you can confirm it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128053/3681880).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `dart.flutterCreateOrganization` setting to control the Organization used when building the identifier (it has the project name added to the end):

https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartfluttercreateorganization