# ADB exited with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter

I'm getting the following error when running my flutter project on Android Emulator. It works fine on iOS Simulator and the project is also fine on my other Mac (runs on both Android and iOS Simulator)

Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/xxxx/Dropbox/Flutter/test_app/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk:
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.

I've cleaned my project and reset my emulator but no luck. It only affects my mac book pro android build.

Flutter doctor also shows no issues

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-CA)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2.1)
    ✗ Verify that all connected devices have been paired with this computer in Xcode.
      If all devices have been paired, libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller may require updating.
      To update with Brew, run:
        brew update
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
        brew unlink usbmuxd
        brew link usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
        brew install ideviceinstaller
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Comment: what is your package name ?

Comment: if using external device, make sure i give access to install via usb

Answer (score 75):

I know two reasons that lead to this error :

- ***Maybe your device/emulator's storage is full***. try deleting some apps
  or similar to free up storage.

Or

- ***Invalid package name*** . for example, using a capital letter in the package name. use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter) to change package name in flutter

Comment: The project name is ok: ```com.example.myproj```

Can I have a capital letter in my app name? Could that be the problem? ```io.flutter.app.MyApp```

Or could the problem be that the main directory name under which the app was created is with a capital letter? ```C:\dev\Myapp\myapp\build\app\outputs...```

Comment: yup, my device storage is full. I have to delete some files and then restart my device

Comment: You can find out which problem you have by running `flutter run -v`

Comment: bad cable do the same error

Answer (score 34):

## Terminal commands for solution

*(worth trying quickly before attempting more complex solutions)*

Run this command to clean out your build/dependencies:

```bash
flutter clean
```

Then run this command to fetch your dependencies again:

```bash
flutter pub get
```

Now try running your project! (`flutter run`)

Answer (score 22):

for my phone (not emulator) i disabled `Verify apps over USB` from `developer options` from my phone settings and it works.

Answer (score 15):

Allow 'installing apps from usb' on your phone if you get this error on physical device

Comment: This additional step made all the difference for me.

Answer (score 11):

This error will appear when your device hasn't enough storage for installing the application if you work with Flutter, the android studio doesn't tell the exact problem.

Comment: the exact answer i was looking, after uninstalling some apps on my emulator the flutter app I debug is working

Answer (score 10):

For me, everything worked after I deleted the `build` directory inside my flutter project.
The build should have the app.apk binary file.

1. Delete that file or delete the whole build folder and run your project.
2. If that doesn't work, just delete your AVD emulator completely and start a new one.

Comment: I tried so many things but deleting my build directory is what finally worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my error by running below code lines because **Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]** is mentioned in the error

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub cache repair`
3. `flutter run`

Answer (score 2):

This problem is mainly due insufficient space because over the time your device collects many logs and cache many stuff.

Try following solutions and one of them could resolve your problem.

**Solution 1**

Run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`.

**Solution 2**

Try removing some apps or disable some services from your device/emulator. As last resort you can simply create new emulator with more space and memory.

**Solution 3**

Make sure your package name is correct and you are following conventions as per Dart/Flutter.

Answer (score 2):

It usually happens with Emulator. Easiest way is to go Andorid Studio > ADB devices. Click on the dropdown arrow on the right side of the emulator name and choose Wipe data.

Comment: Quick solution. Great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this off and on for a year, here is what I just noticed that makes it work or not work on my system.

I discovered tonight that if I have my virus protection running my emulator stalls in the
" --->    Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk. 
and I just get a white screen. I turn off the virus protection and it works fine in debug mode. 
If its on I have to keep going to the terminal and doing: " flutter run " to see any changes I have made. 
Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved these issues using these steps .I am using BlueStack Emulator for running Emulator.

***Steps:-***

1. Go to setting of BlueStack Emulator
2. Then click on Advance and then
3. Turn on Android Debug Bridge (ADB)

I resolved these issues using these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Google service scans apk and consider it harmful and block from installation

**Disable/ turn off the google service app scan.** in your emulator

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously installed apps on your Android Emulator,
Try uninstalling some already installed apps from the Android Emulator by going to...

---

*Settings  >>  Apps & notifications  >>  app_to_be_uninstalled  >>  Uninstall*

---

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, on Android Studio, open the Logcat tab. You will get a ton of messages, but somewhere in there will be the answer.

For example, if the package name is invalid, you will see:

```
W/ActivityManager: Invalid packageName: your.bad.package.name
```

Try using the search field in the upper right of the logcat window to filter the messages.

Also, you need to make sure that the device you are working with is selected in the target dropdown at the top of the window. Often, if you get this error, Android Studio will automatically remove your device from the target list and switch it to a different device. You might have to unplug and plug back in your USB cable to get it to appear again. Then select it, and open the Logcat tab at the bottom. The messages from the previous session will be saved and you can look through them.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had the app already installed on the device. Once I deleted it, and then tried to install via `adb` again, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had `Universal ADB Driver` installed in my system for fastboot and stuff. I uninstalled and it worked for me.

Also I had to delete `adb` directory from root to remove it completely.

Answer (score 0):

> You can apply some simple steps

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub cache repair` or manually

> example

[image]

finally

4. `flutter pub get`
5. `flutter run`

> i'pe your problem will solved!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

1. Try connect using wifi option.
2. After connecting ADT using wifi then this error only come if wifi connection is lost.
3. Enable wifi connect option in Developer Option and Pair android studio using QR code or Enter code manually.
4. In addition : Allow USB install.
5. Also disable Verify app over USB, OR if you do not want to disable then for 10 sec prompt will be displayed to confirm the installation if not confirmed then this error will be displayed because by default installation is denied.