# Hey everyone, i start using android studio and working on flutter project but i face this error every time Error: ADB exited with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter

[image: 1]

I start using android studio and working on the flutter project but I face this error every time Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

Comment: check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56417433/12813115). Hope it helps.

Comment: Everytime i get this error. I usually first try to delete my emulator and create a new one. Most of the time the emulator storage gets full that's why you might see this error.

Comment: does this work on the default project? I.e. when you just create a project.