# vs code debugging not working after package name change in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

I already changed the package name of my app, but debugging not working able to run project after flutter run command but not able to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did in vscode:

In Search, turn on `Regular Expression` and use following command. *(you should change example_flutter to your existed package name)*

```
(import 'package:)example_flutter
```

In Replace, use following command: *(you should change new_project_name to your favorite)*

```
$1new_project_name
```

[image]

Tested in flutter-desktop, For Android and iOS, I thought you have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter) already.

**Edit:**

The OP's issue is sloved by deleted `.vscode` and restart vscode, I thought the issue was changing the name in `pubspec.yaml`, so made a wrong solution above.

Comment: I already changed the package name of my app, but debugging not working able to run project after flutter run command but not able to debug.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Have you tried to delete `.vscode` file and fully restart vscode? I always did this If not working.