# Can't run any other flutter app except for one

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, terminal

I've cloned a new flutter project from git

When I try to run I get the following error

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'application_flutter_todo' in 'package:application_flutter_todo/utils/constants/api.dart'.
../../.pub-cache/git/flutter_maximo_api-35d1fef13c59a0e7fb70a20916adf1f9d26eac02/lib/src/maximo_api.dart:5:8: Error: Not found:
'package:application_flutter_todo/utils/constants/api.dart'
import 'package:application_flutter_todo/utils/constants/api.dart';
       ^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:package%3Aapplication_flutter_todo%2Futils%2Fconstants%2Fapi.dart; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:*
URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:604:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:799:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:472:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:38:22)
#5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:149:27)
#6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:8:30)
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
Failed to build bundle.
Failed to package /Users/Mohammad/Gemba/application_traxxion.
```

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

It appears that your application still contains the default signing identifier.
Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Note that the current project doesn't have the import 'package:application_flutter_todo' statement.
That statement belongs to another app and is not in the current project that I'm trying to run.

I've tried,
1- flutter clean
2- updating flutter
3- updating packages
4- cleaning the product
5- cleaning the project
6- running the project from terminal, visual studio code, xcode all three gave the same result.

Nothing of the above have worked.

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies, you should change your package name and BundleId for Android & iOS respectively. You shouldn't be using the default ones.

You can find how to do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550358/10830091).