# How to change app package name in Flutter without using Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

As you know, app package name (**com.****.******) is very important thing in Flutter app, it is also being used in app's link on Play Store, and some other places.

So, I have a app package name which is automatically created by flutter when creating app via command line: com.example.app

How can I change it properly? There are lots of files and folders named after the app package name, so changing app package name manually without causing error is something I seek.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change it in

- android/app/build.gradle
- android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/personal_web/MainActivity.kt
- android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: also on android/app/src/main/profile/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 5):

There's a useful package for changing it but it works well with android, I didn't try for IOS.

Firstly install the package:

```
  change_app_package_name: ^1.0.0
```

Then in terminal in your project paths do these commands:

```
flutter pub get
```

Then write the line below and use the unique name you want after `com.` then press enter:

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.myuniquename.flutter_app
```

it will update files and delete old package name.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change it in the following files.

- android/app/build.gradle
- android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/personal_web/MainActivity.kt
- android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
- android/app/src/main/profile/AndroidManifest.xml
- android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

The most appropriate command would be `flutter create --org com.changehere -a kotlin -i swift yourapp_name`

Comment: This command can be used when creating a new project, but cannot modify an existing project identifier.   But still valid solution 1- create new project with this command then transfer lib and other files to new package.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html):

> Your application ID is defined with the applicationId property in your
>   module's build.gradle file [...]

Flutter: Open `/android/app/build.gradle`, scroll down to `applicationId`.

Comment: so, you're saying no need change anything else?

Comment: I would be surprised, if you really need to change each file.