# How can I change the package name in flutter while the application is related to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I want to change the package name of my android application so that it changes in my project in Firebase.
Is there any solution for that? 
Or should I delete it from my Firebase project and re-add it?
Thanks for advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change package name in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter)

Comment: you can add a new application in that same Firebase project and specify the package name of your current app there.

Comment: just change your applicationId inside app's build.gradle , that's all.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you can just add a new Android app to your existing Firebase project with the new package name. After doing this, download the updated *`google-services.json`* and add it to your app.

Note that Firebase does not use the actual package name from your Java code, but uses the applicationId from your app's *`build.gradle`* file.

When you initially create a project in Android Studio, the package name and application id will have the same value. But if you refactor your code into a different package, the application id won't be updated. That explains why the app will continue to work after such a refactoring.