# Flutter package name for googleplaystore

Tags: flutter, package-name

Hi I searched how to change package name in flutter.But I'm using Firebase admob in my app. My app package name is

```
  "package_name": "com.example.flutter_apptry"
```

I tryed to upload the app to the store but google says

```
Since "com.example" is restricted, you need to use a different package name.
```

So What should I do

Thank you.
I'm using firebase ads. in "google-services.json "  my app package name is

```
  "package_name": "com.example.flutter_apptry"
```

As my tought I replaced all the package name but now ad service is not working.How can I fix it

Comment: Why cannot you rename it?

Comment: I think if i rename it ad service will broken

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your package ID. "example" is not allowed over the Play Store.

If you want to get more info about it, check the docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

Renaming a Flutter app is relative simple in just a few steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550358/3743245

Comment: My application ID is         applicationId "com.example.flutter_apptry"
If i change it and Rename Flutter app then the ad service will still work ?