# how can i solve flutter error The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined

Tags: flutter, dart

I have flutter project and i used visual studio code
it ran android but doesn't run IOS

debug console saw me error

> Unable to install /Users/a/Desktop/xeta-flutter-main/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on A2DF75F6-E581-47AE-89FB-2875BBFFB2A8. This is sometimes caused by a malformed plist file:
> ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
> An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
> Failed to install the requested application
> The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
> Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
> Command: xcrun simctl install A2DF75F6-E581-47AE-89FB-2875BBFFB2A8 /Users/a/Desktop/xeta-flutter-main/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
> Error launching application on iPhone 11.

and my Info.plist is here

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>Xeta App</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>xetaapp</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.802724704125-tr7nj48c74uifdrk0ar9pp22gh6vvt3n</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>None</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
        <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>https</string>`enter code here`
            <string>http</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
        <string>Main</string>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
        <true/>
        <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have debugged 3 days but still solved yet

please help me guys

Comment: Is the identifier you use formatted as 3 words separated by dots? so like `com.mydomain.myapp`? If it has more or fewer parts, it won't work on iOS.

Comment: yes my bundle identifier is com.xetaapp.xpop
but still run yet

Answer (score 0):

Error refer to `bundle Identifier`. In your `iOS` folder open `Runner.xcworkspace` with `xcode` and then in `Signing & Capabilities` make sure you have not error in bundle Identifier. If you have an error change it to another one. like image blew:

[image]

Comment: thank bro i find it but i'am still run yet
i dont't forget your kindness

Answer (score 0):

Your identifier is stored in your `xcworkspace` file, as you can see it's a variable in your `info.plist` file:

```xml
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

So open up your `.xcworkspace` file and make sure it's set to the value you need it to be. Keep in mind that it needs to be 3 dot-separated words, as I noted in the comment earlier.

See also the comments underneath this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550358/15469537

Comment: thank you but same error showed me
i'don't forget your kindness