# Do I need to generate a new key after changing my Flutter app package name?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, apk, android-keystore

I created a flutter application and generated a key for it to upload to play-store, but because it was named com.example.testapp play-store didn't allow me to upload it and I tried changing the name. But after the application was uploaded it kept crashing, it wasn't running on any device and I figured that it might be because I changed the package name incorrectly.

After following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter), I successfully changed the app package name.

Now when I am uploading again do I delete the previous app from the playstore? And do I need to generate a new key or just create a new bundle and upload it?

Comment: You should create a new app in google console because it's a new package name .

Comment: And delete the previous .jks file from my app folder? Create a new key as well right?

Comment: The package name has to be changed at multiple points. The uploading signature should be independent. Before uploading the app to Google test it locally on a device.

Comment: You don't necessary need to use a new `.jks` keystore file for each of your apps. Just can just use the same keystore and the same alias for all of your app or create an alias for each of your apps. Or you can create a new `.jks` keystore app for each for your app. That's is up to you.